# Don't see my AspNet Identity tables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I built a MVC site with Identity that will be replacing an old site that uses Asp.Net 2.0 security. I used a local database to create all of my pages. I'm finally at a point that I want to use my hosting provider's SQL Server. I published my code and changed the connection string to point to the hosted SQL Server. Migrations are turned on and I even ran "Update-Database". However, I don't see tables like "AspNetRoles" or "AspNetUsers". I went ahead and changed the connection string on my local machine to point to the hosted SQL server to make it easier to test out. I tried logging in with one of the accounts I created previously and it said it couldn't be found. That's actually a good thing since it tells me that it's pointing to a new database. I went ahead and created a new user hoping it would auto create the database tables. The new user worked and I can log in with the account but I still can't see the tables when I look at it through SQL Studio Mgr. Yes, I did refresh the tables under SQL Server and still don't see them. Any suggestions on why I'm not seeing the Identity tables?

Comment: did you try to open that connection string in sql server ? make sure that the connection string is correct.

Comment: Yes, I have that database open in SQL Studio Mgr. I'm baffled where it's putting the data.